# Crontab is disappearing when ever we edit it

Tags: cron

Crontab is disappearing whenever we edit it?

```
crontab -l
```

**no crontab for the**  is the error

the user is High privileged access account

What can be the root cause? 
Any suggestions where to check?

Comment: You've started with no crontab; what commands did you enter next in order to edit the crontab?

Comment: Is `crond` running ? Did you edit the crontab with `crontab -e` ? Could it be that you are confusing the system crontab with crontab of a user ? (Users, by default, have a empty crontab so in that case it's perfectly normal)

Comment: I gave crontab -e and then saved it and when i checked , it disappeared .As a result of this the next jobs didnt run and we had a major issue . we have raised a case with redhat to see if there is an issue with the recent update .. Have anyone noticed such issues previously

Comment: yes crond is up and running .. this user is our main user and all our jobs run with this user

Comment: `crontab -e` uses a temporary file (but the changes are saved by cron) so it's perfectly normal that the file disappeared. Did you add a cronline (in the correct cron-syntax)  ? No cronlines = no crontab

Comment: Yes I have commented one line and saved the file and the file disappeared after that. Is there a way where i can check any related logs for this activity ?

Comment: What Unix are you running?

Comment: we are using Korn shell.Linux  3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 16 14:19:51 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux